Problem with longtable-style section glossaries printing an empty line
I'm writing a document with some fairly extensive cross-referencing, and with a lot of help from various related posts on this forum and others, I have glossaries-extra with bib2gls working fairly well. There is one problem I just can't find a solution to.
When printing section glossaries (printunsrtglossaryunit) using a longtable based style, any sections which do not include the "last" glossary entry (ie zyx alphabetical) add an empty row to the glossary table. The full glossary is fine, and sections which include the "last" entry are also fine.
What is causing this extra space in the table to appear? I assume it is some unprinted element (like a label or ref or something), but I can't find out where it is coming from, or how to suppress it / get rid of it.
I compiled this MWE in Overleaf, to make sure my personal setup wasn't introducing the bug.
MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[record, stylemods=all]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrRecordCounter{section}

\newglossaryentry{abc}{name = {ABC Name},description = {abc}}

\newglossaryentry{def}{name = {DEF Name},description = {def}}

\newglossaryentry{xyz}{name = {XYZ Name},description = {xyz}}

\newglossaryentry{zyx}{name = {ZYX Name},description = {zyx}}

\begin{document}
    
    \section{Section One}
    
    \gls{abc}
    
    \setglossarystyle{longheaderborder}
    \printunsrtglossaryunit{section}
    \lipsum[66]
    
    \section{Section Two}
    
    \gls{def}
    \gls{zyx}
    
    \setglossarystyle{longheaderborder}
    \printunsrtglossaryunit{section}
    \lipsum[75]
        
    \printunsrtglossary
    
\end{document}


